# Create PHP table from array

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

I'd like to have a function that creates database-tables:

input:

1. $tableName
2. $tableFields (parameters array)

output: new DB TABLE

---

The two dimension array contains the fields detentions:

- a[0][0] = firstName
- a[0][1] = varchar[25]
- a[1][0] = lastName
- a[1][1] = varchar[30]

The output is a table named $tableName with two fields firstName and lastName.

---

I think that I can build a create query by looping the array, yet I don't know how to tell php to commit this command and actually create the DB table.

Comment: I could write up  this function with about the same amount of keystrokes I've used for this comment; have you tried something, *anything*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createTable( $tableName,$a) {
    global $con; //database connection
    $query = "CREATE TABLE $tableName ";
    $temp = "";
    for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++) {
        $temp .= $a[$i][0] . " " . $a[$i][1] . ",";
    }
    if($temp!='') {
     $query .= substr($temp,0,-1);
     mysqli_query($con,$query);
    }
    else {
      print "No column names provided";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just have a look into the mysqli module of PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php

There you can create a connection to a database, perform queries etc.

Comment: This is fit to be a comment; you have enough rep points for it.

Comment: As far as I can see the requester does not need a solution to fetch data from MySQL but he wants to iterate an array. If you want to go with the MySQL then please be more specific and come at least with some code examples or alike

Comment: I´m sorry but in his last sentence he wrote that he know how to loop over the array and create the query but he does not know how to commit the query to the database, which can be done through mysqli as i hinted.